# Facebook Connect - Using OAuth for Authentication, but with FB:login-button - Allowed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, xfbml, facebook-oauth

Previously i used the JavaScript API for Facebook Connect, so i had the `fb:login-button` XFBML tag, which when clicked would perform the login.

But now, i'm using OAuth authentication (server-side), but i still wish to have the button (which when clicked, would simply redirect to the URL on my server which does the OAuth stuff).

Is this allowed?

Can i simply style a regular anchor/button to look like the [Facebook login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)?

I don't want to have to include the Javascript SDK library simply to render out the button. I don't care about the code behind the button, just the UI.

FYI - i'm using the Facebook C# SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are doing is allowed. I would suggest taking a look at the tutorial I posted which does almost exactly what you are talking about. You can find that tutorial [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website&referringTitle=Getting%20Started). No need for the Javascript SDK for that scenario.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - followed that tutorial (which is great btw). On a side note - have you got any documentation/reference for implementing a single-sign-on with the toolkit? (e.g an action filter), that checks if the user is auth'ed to facebook, if so, see if they have a account with my website, if so automatically sign them in, etc. I used to do this via the JavaScript SDK on the client-side. Great work on the toolkit by the way!

Comment: I'm wondering about the same thing, though I'm not using the C# library, I'm writing my own PHP calls, and I'm wondering if the OAuth links should be any different to have the "login"/"authenticate" flow vs. the typical "authorize" flow ... or does facebook use the same for both?